# *ngIf undefined error in *ngFor when showing error response

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have an Angular application and a Laravel based API. I do request validation using request classes in Laravel and getting validation errors in JSON format. I have validation for an input array and the validation message is appearing in the following format :

```
"validation": {
  "items.0": [
    "item required"
  ],
  "items.1": [
    "item required"
  ]
}
```

I have an `ngFor` loop which is used for creating the input fields for `items`. The HTML is as

```
<tr *ngFor="let name of items.controls; index as idx"
   class="form-group">
   <td>
      <p>
         <input [formControlName]="idx" type="text">
      </p>
      <small *ngIf="validationError['items'][idx]" class="text-danger">
          {{validationError['items'][idx]}}
      </small>
   </td>
</tr>
```

This form is in a modal box. But with this code, when I try to access open the modal, it is showing javascript error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

This is because the error is populated only when clicking on Submit. Before that there is no error. How can I validate this condition ?

Comment: Where's the error coming from? What is `items`, `validationError`?

Comment: I am assigning the validation error to a variable `validationError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `validationError['items'][idx]`, you should aim `validationError['items.' + idx]`.
The error comes from the fact there's no property `items` in your validationError object